# Не могу выводить в консоль, после работы с файлами

Tags: pascal, файлы, консоль

Необходимо сделать файл рандомных действительных чисел от 100 до 1000, далее считать этот же файл и преобразовать в типизированный файл целых чисел и на последок вывести содержимое типизированного файла в консоль. 
Проблема появляется при выводе в консоль, выдаёт exitcode 103(file not open), пытался добавлять `rewrite(output)`, компилируется, но ничего не выводит.

```
var a: array [1..100] of real;
    b: array [1..100] of integer;
    num: file of integer;
    i,j,k,n:integer;
    d:real;
begin
    assign(output,'file.txt');
    rewrite(output);
    read(n);
    randomize;
    for i:=1 to n do a[i]:=100+random(901)+random;//числа 100..1000 real
    for i:=1 to n do write(a[i]:0:5,' ');//выводим числа в файл
    close(output);

    assign(input,'file.txt');
    reset(input);
    assign(num,'perevod.txt');
    rewrite(num);
    i:=1;
    while not eof do
    begin
        read(d);//читаем когда-то записанные числа
        k:=round(d);
        write(num,k);//записываем в типизированный файл
    end;
    close(input); close(num);

    assign(num,'perevod.txt');
    reset(num); i:=1;
    while not eof(num) do
    begin
        read(num,k);берём числа из типизированного файла
        b[i]:=k;inc(i);
    end;
    close(num);
    //rewrite(output);
    for i := 1 to n do write(a[i],' ');//вывод массива в консоль
end.
```

Comment: ну я бы сказал бы, что это знак перейти на джаву

Comment: Сам пишу на шарпе, но другу нужно помочь с паскалем, вот и мучаюсь.

Comment: искренне сочувствую))

Comment: Отладчик ваш друг.

Comment: Вы сами связали `output` с файлом: `assign(output,'file.txt');`, поэтому на консоль ничего и не выводится.

Comment: а есть ли возможность отвязать?

Comment: @koshachok Насчёт отвязать не знаю, но можно просто использовать свои выделенные переменные для работы с файлами.

Answer (score 1):

uses crt;
может спасти. Более подробная информация уже зависит от версии паскаля.